# Makefile for compiling c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm using g++ on linux and writing multiple cpp programs. For ex. I have ex1.cpp, ex2.cpp, bot.cpp.

All these cpp programs are inside the same folder. I want to use make to compile individual programs as in "make ex1" should compile ex1.cpp and not the other cpp files. "make bot" should only compile bot.cpp

The compilation command I intend to execute is :

```
g++ -o bot bot.cpp
```

I don't want to write target and dependency in MakeFile for every cpp program I create in the folder and I don't want to compile all cpp's at one go using *.cpp.

Is it possible first of all to achieve this ? Is yes please suggest a solution

Comment: Don't forget to add `-Wall` to your command line flags !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution to your question :

Just run **make ex1** in the command line and it will compile using the command `g++ ex1.cpp -o ex1`.

**If** you want to dynamically include libraries/shared objects or add additional flags then you should create a make file or follow the procedure suggested by Lukasz (Too complicated though).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a makefile. `make ex1` should already do what you want.